# Asp.net AjaxToolkit TabContainter Active Tab changed - previous tab

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

Is there any way I can find what the previous active was when the active tab changed event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found a very simple solution.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lasttab = 0;
    function tabChanged(sender, args) {
        // do what ever i want with lastTab value
        lasttab = sender.get_activeTabIndex();
    }
</script>
```

Asp.net

```
    <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1"  
         runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" OnClientActiveTabChanged="tabChanged">
```